# How do I calculate the difference over time using one database table?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have one table that has three columns: **Player**, **Score**, and **Date**.

I want to create a query that will compare the total score for each player with what the total score was one week ago.

For example, I want to be able to gather information so I am able to output:

```
1st place this week: **Bob** (**1875** Score) - up by **7** points since last week!
```

Thanks

EDIT: Adding more info as requested.

Currently, I have several queries that display data such as total score, average score, etc.

When I enter this data on the website, I manually calculate how much the difference was. Example:

> ```
> Player            Champion    Role    Games   Ratio   Sum Of Kills   Sum Of Deaths
> Startmanningup    Ezreal      Adc     8       4.20        63             15
> Voyboy            Tristana    Adc     4       3.33        30              9
> ```

If Startmanningups ratio last week was 4.18, I want a column to show the difference was 0.02.

My table info looks like this:

> ```
> Player       Champion    Role    Kills    Deaths  Assists Win     Time
> lord zosh    master yi   jungle   11        2        6    1     2014-06-27
> lolbree      lucian      adc       7        0        7    1     2014-06-27
> ```

EDIT 2:

OK I can get a query that will display the number I want to compare to.. but I have no idea how to make a query with a column that actually displays the score difference (in Access I keep getting an aggregate query error).

Comment: Please provide sample data and your best effort to solve the problem.

Comment: Database is MS Access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For test data in a table named [Scores]

```
Date        Player  Score
----------  ------  -----
2014-06-23  Gord       30
2014-06-23  Hank       23
2014-06-30  Gord       27
2014-06-30  Hank       28
```

the query

```sql
SELECT 
    cur.Date, 
    cur.Player, 
    prev.Score AS ScoreLastWeek,
    cur.Score AS ScoreNow,
    cur.Score - prev.Score AS Change
FROM
    Scores cur
    INNER JOIN
    Scores prev
        ON cur.Player = prev.Player
            AND cur.Date = DateAdd("d", 7, prev.Date)
```

returns

```
Date        Player  ScoreLastWeek  ScoreNow  Change
----------  ------  -------------  --------  ------
2014-06-30  Gord               30        27      -3
2014-06-30  Hank               23        28       5
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it all in one single SQL statement, instead of using more than one query?

I don't mind if the answer is in postgresql or another non-messy sql language (access sql has too many brackets)

Answer (score 0):

To get current score average:

```
select player, avg(score)
from score_table
group by player
order by avg;
```

To get the score average a week ago you could do:

```
select player, avg(score)
from score_table
where score_table.date < now()-'1 week'::interval
group by player
order by avg;
```

That could get you started to get some data to work with and combine in your app to produce the desired output.

Comment: The question is tagged "ms-access" and this doesn't look like Access syntax.

Comment: Getting a syntax error - is there a function similar to this in MS Access?

Comment: The Q was not tagged [ms-access] initially! I'm not using that and has never been, but a quick google look gives us this: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/add-to-or-subtract-from-date-and-time-values-HP001098485.aspx Could that be of any help?

Comment: OK now I keep getting "aggregate query" errors.. I made a query that displays the avg score from 1 week ago.. I am trying to make another query that compares that avg score with the current avg score, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Can I not just use some kind of SQL statement with a sub-select?